# How to edit Software and Updates' options in terminal?

Tags: software-sources

I need to edit Software and Updates' options in terminal. Namely the options:

- `Install updates from`
- and automatical updates period, whether to check for them etc. etc.

[image]

Where can I find this options in the file system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The *"Install updates from"* option is basically your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. It can be edited with this command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Some lines are commented (with `#`) when they are disabled. Just remove the comment from the front to enable them.
2. If you're referring to the other options on the page, I can only find some of them:

   - *"When there are other updates"* is this dconf key, time is in days:

     ```
     /com/ubuntu/update-notifier/regular-auto-launch-interval
     ```
   - *"Notify me of a new Ubuntu version"* is in the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`. Edit it with this command:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
     ```

     There will be a line starting with `Prompt=`. Change this to `never`, `normal` or `lts`. It is also explained in the comments.

   The other options I'm not sure of. I'm guessing that they are managed by a background service running as root. If you're interested, I found this with a `dconf watch /` command while changing the settings.